# Mysql CTEs problem- why do I keep getting syntax error?

Tags: mysql

So I am trying to use CTE

```
with assigned_users as ( 
SELECT e.id as `process_id`, e.name as `process_name`, organizations_id, e.store_users_id, eau.store_users_id 
from evaluations e 
inner join organizations o on e.organizations_id = o.id  
inner join evaluation_assigned_users eau on eau.evaluations_id = e.id 
where o.custom_url  = 'forevernew' and e.name = 'Opening Checklist'
order by created_date desc, evaluation_groups_id  desc)

select *
from assigned_users
```

but I am getting an error --------

> SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
> the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'assigned_users as (  SELECT e.id as `process_id`,
> e.name as `process_name`, org' at line 1

Comment: What version of MySql are you using? As an aside, this is a fairly frivolous use of a CTE and is actually causing you more problems than it solves. Your ordering should be on the final query and not within the CTE, but to do that ordering outside of the CTE you'd need to include those columns in the CTE, then remove them from the column list of the outer query. You're just as well executing the query as it is and removing the CTE syntax all together (unless there is more the query that you are not sharing)

Comment: I didnt get it at all can u elaborate more?

Comment: I am using DBeaver version 22.2.2.202210092258  Mysql driver - 5 binaries

Comment: DBeaver is an IDE and does not relate to your version of MySQL. What does `select version();` return for you if you run that against your database?

Comment: With regard to the rest of the comment what I was saying is that the CTE serves no purpose here other than to make your query essentially incorrect (although it may well still run). There is no requirement for the query engine to respect the ordering in your CTE. I've put an [example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7WEwsFrZ) with annotations to try and demonstrate what I mean.